# BigInteger loop executing infinitely

Tags: java, biginteger

```
while(true) {
    if(((d.multiply(e)).mod(phi1)).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        break;
    d.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

I have the following code in my program, which means that

```
while(true) {
    if((d*e)%phil==1) 
        break;
    d++;
}
```

Here, `e=17`, `phil=12816` and `d=1` initially.

But even after waiting for a long time, the loop is still executing. What could be the mistake?

Comment: change `d.add(BigInteger.ONE)` for `d = d.add(BigInteger.ONE)`, BigInteger is immutable.

Comment: Is this your whole loop? It is more readable to actually use the exit condition: `while( ! d.multiply(e).... ) { d = d.add( BigInteger.ONE ); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BigInteger` is immutable and all operations on it return a new instance instead of modifying the current one. Thus `d.add(BigInteger.ONE);` does not change the value of `d`.

To fix the issue write: `d = d.add(BigInteger.ONE);`